# OData select query not working in ASP.NET WebAPI beta

Tags: odata, asp.net-web-api

I'm playing around with the WebAPI beta, and it seems that selects have no effect on the response of an action returning an IQueryable. 
Eg:

**http://localhost:62689/api/product?$select=Id,Name**

Expected:

```
<Product>
<Id>1</Id>
<Name>Product 1</Name>
</Product>
```

Actual result:

```
<Product>
<Id>1</Id>
<Name>Product 1</Name>
<ItemsInStock>6</ItemsInStock>
<Price>49.99</Price>
<Created>2012-01-15T00:00:00</Created>
</Product>
```

Are there limitations on OData support for WebAPI?

I've tried other queries on this set of data (like top, filter) and they work fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Web API does not support the OData $select query.

> The current support of query string parameters is limited to $top, $skip, $filter and $orderby.

Take a look at [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1771116.aspx/1?OData%20Support) forum post for more details.

Comment: As of version 5.0 $select and $expand are now supported. https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24select%20and%20%24expand%20support&referringTitle=Specs